# How do I set a Breakpoint at VirtualProtect in Ollydbg?

Tags: ollydbg

I am using Olly 1.10
How do I set a Breakpoint at VirtualProtect in Ollydbg?
I understand that this is a simple question, but I am new to Olly and need a simple answer.

Answer (score 2):

**ollydbg 1.10**

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>
Type in the Dialog's Edit box
`kernel32.VirtualProtect`
<kbd>ok</kbd>    <kbd>f2</kbd>

using Commandline Plugin
<kbd>alt+f1</kbd> -> Type Bp VirtualProtect -> ok

**ollydbg 2.01**

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>
start Typing in the Dialog's Edit box
`kernel32.VirtualP`
the list box will show the apis that match the pattern 
`select follow expression`
<kbd>f2</kbd>

Comment: Thanks blabb, That worked a treat. I misunderstood your reply at first and,    as a result, found that I could also enter 'BP VirtualProtect' in the 'Command' Box to set the BreakPoint.

Comment: yeah using the default commandline plugin  btw if the reply answered your query please mark it as such